# Assign to new ID based multiple columns (in R)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

This is a bit of a weird one. I've got a dataset with thousands of rows. I can't share it. The headers include:

- year
- reporter ID
- reporter name
- building ID
- building name
- controller ID
- controller name
- latitude (for some)
- longitude (for some)
- other columns not used for identification

The buildings are my unit of analysis. However, there are problems.

First, the data was entered manually, so name things that should be constant change year to year (eg "Business Inc." and then "Business Incorporated"). And worse, the building ID changes when the controller or the reporter change (which happens when buildings get sold).

For example, in 2015 a building might be called "Big Building", have a building id of "1111" and have a controller called "Tiny Tim". Then in 2016 it is sold, now it appears as "The Big Building", the building id is "4567", and the controller is "Tiny Tim". It is the same building, but this dataset doesn't track that. This is my problem.

**What I want:** to create a new ID column that actually identifies buildings, and does not change across years or reporters or controllers. This ID could then be used in conjunction with year to lookup the reporter and controller (if desired).

But, I don't know how to do this. I figure there must be something that can look at 'building name' (noting it can have minor changes year on year) as well as the other supporting ID columns and estimate whether to assign a new ID in a new column, or if an ID has already been assigned to this building and then apply that one. Does that make sense?

Can someone please point me in the right direction to get started?

Comment: due to the inability to see anything, even a dummy example, and the variation in the data, it's probably not able to be fully automated, but will require you arranging the data and just sifting through it would be my guess.

Comment: Yeah, this problem sucks. There are some things you can try but whatever way you pick will be a ton of grinding. If you have <5k observations, just eyeball every one. If you have >500k, you can look at the `stringdist` package ([link here](https://github.com/markvanderloo/stringdist)) to get an idea of how to compare building/names. Or use lat/long to calculate distance between candidates, etc. But it's a ton of work no matter what.

Comment: @JesseTweedle you might be onto something if the lat/long data is reliable. Could do a distance matrix and then create a lookup to use from that.

Comment: This is essentially a data linkage problem - an internal linkage of one dataset against itself. Maybe take a look at the RecordLinkage package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html , which will allow you to compare phonetic and other variations of strings and distances between numeric variables (like long/lat roughly are).

Comment: FYI the lat/long data is present for about 65% of the rows, but I have been told that some times it was entered as the building lat/long, and other times the lat/long of the controlling company. So I wouldn't rely only on it.